# VtigerCRM customer portal can not connect to the CRM server_Authorization Required

Tags: php, http-authentication, vtiger

We are using VtigerCRM on our local server which provides ldap authentication for http access, also have the customer portal of vtiger on another machine.

When customer portal connects to the server, this authorization problem occurs. The complete error is pasted here: http://pastebin.com/iNLUP390

Configuration on php files on both machines looks to be correct:

config.inc.php on vtigerCRM server has new line:

```
$PORTAL_URL = 'http://vtiger-server/vtigercrm';
```

PortalConfig.php on customer portal side contains:

```
$Server_Path = 'http://vtiger-server/vtigercrm';
$Authenticate_Path = 'http://vtiger-client/customerportal';
```

Since server is protected by an authentication layer, so the right username and password should be inserted somewhere that I have no idea.

Someone suggested to insert the username and password of the server into the nusoap.php file, but I don't know how to modify it. Here is my nusoap.php file: http://pastebin.com/kpWPAkq7

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For your login failure you must turn off your error report in vtigerCRM .

```
error_reporting(0);
```

for more information you can check

[http://www.samdoit.com/news/VtigerCRM-customer-portal-connect-problem/](http://click%20here%20to%20Know%20more%20information)